# Capitalize only after whitespace oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Supposing I've got this string:

```
LOREM IPSUM;DOLOR SIT
```

I need to capitalize the first letter of a word only if it is preceded by a whitespace.
For example, if I use INITCAP, i get:

```
select initcap('LOREM IPSUM;DOLOR SIT') from dual;
-> Lorem Ipsum;Dolor Sit
```

Instead, I need the output to be:

```
Lorem Ipsum;dolor Sit
```

Is there a way to configure INITCAP to capitalize only after whitespace?
If not, can you give me some ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to separate each string (delimited by space) and work on it as follows:

```
SQL> select T.STR,
  2         LISTAGG(
  3           UPPER(SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(T.STR,'[^ ]+',1, LEVELS.COLUMN_VALUE),1,1))
  4           || LOWER(SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(T.STR,'[^ ]+',1, LEVELS.COLUMN_VALUE),2)),' ')
  5         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY LEVELS.COLUMN_VALUE) AS RESULT
  6   FROM 
  7  (SELECT 'LOREM IPSUM;DOLOR SIT' AS STR from dual
  8   union all
  9   SELECT 'TEJASH HINGU SO,ANSWER WEIZEN;QUESTION' AS STR from dual) t -- YOUR DATA
 10  cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 11  connect by  level <= length (regexp_replace(T.str, '[^ ]+'))  + 1)
 12  as sys.OdciNumberList)) levels
 13  GROUP BY T.STR;

STR                                    RESULT
-------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
LOREM IPSUM;DOLOR SIT                  Lorem Ipsum;dolor Sit
TEJASH HINGU SO,ANSWER WEIZEN;QUESTION Tejash Hingu So,answer Weizen;question

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you may have more than one space together and you should not lose them

```
-- Oracle 12+
with s as 
(select 'LOREM IPSUM;DOLOR SIT   DOLOR   SIT' str from dual union all
 select 'TEJASH  HINGU SO,ANSWER   WEIZEN;QUESTION' from dual
)
select s.str,
listagg(
    regexp_substr(s_str, '^\s+') ||
    upper(regexp_substr(s_str, '\S')) ||
    lower(regexp_substr(s_str, '\S(\S+)', 1, 1, 'i', 1))
    )
within group (order by rn) ls
from s,
lateral
(select rownum rn, regexp_substr(s.str, '(^|\s+)\S*', 1, level) s_str
 from dual
 connect by level <= regexp_count(s.str, '^|\s+')
) l
group by s.str;

STR                                       LS
----------------------------------------- ------------------------------------------
LOREM IPSUM;DOLOR SIT   DOLOR   SIT       Lorem Ipsum;dolor Sit   Dolor   Sit
TEJASH  HINGU SO,ANSWER   WEIZEN;QUESTION Tejash  Hingu So,answer   Weizen;question
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this

```
with data
  as (select 'LOREM IPSUM;DOLOR SIT' as str
        from dual
      )
    ,split_data
     as(
SELECT lower(trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^ ]+', 1, LEVEL))) split_str
      ,upper(substr(lower(trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^ ]+', 1, LEVEL))),1,1))
        ||substr(lower(trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^ ]+', 1, LEVEL)))
                ,2,length(str)
       ) as capital_word
  FROM data
CONNECT BY instr(str, ' ', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
       )
select listagg(capital_word,' ')
 from split_data
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6e3dc670ee678d5622de3ef51c7c480c